# Text overflow from Background Image

Tags: html, css, background-image, background-color

Hi I would like my background image to wrap up the content/text inside it. The text seems to overflow from the background image and overlaps other text. It all works well on desktop but when I try to open Codepen in my iPhone, it didnt turn out as how it is expected to be. Please refer to pictures I attach here.

```
`https://codepen.io/sharonloh/full/pBrdRd`
```

I am new to coding and I have tried various ways after trying to search for solution but nothing seems to work.

[Text overflowing from background image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOvvc.jpg)

Comment: What do you have tried so far to solve the problem? Please include a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to make the question clearer.

Comment: please add your html/css

Comment: if you remove the height it wouldnt work?

Comment: it seems to work now, thank you very much

Comment: @Sharon no problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the picture you posted, there are various potential resolutions.

The first potential issue is that you have set a background image but not set other background attributes.

One way to resolve your issue would be to add a `repeat` to your css:

```
 background-image: (your image);
 background-repeat: repeat;
```

Add this to your css for the image/background class. If you only want the image to repeat vertically, you can use `repeat-y` instead of `repeat`. Similar for horizontal/repeat-x. Another way would be to use `background-size:cover`. 
If you only want it to repeat on smaller screens you can add a media-query and add the extra attribute there.

Do add your css/html in future (now would be preferable! You can edit your question to add code). It helps to give a clearer picture of how to resolve the problem.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you much for your help and advice, unfortunately it didn't work. I have also added my CodePen link.. Sorry it's my first time with coding and this is driving me crazy.

Comment: @Sharon you are closing off the image div before it even gets to the howto. do you want the image to cover the entire page or just the recipe bit?

Comment: Just the recipe bit

Comment: set your height to auto (instead of 1650 - which is bad practice anyway - and add the image class to the howto (so its div class ="image howto" . Here's a codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MRvXLm I'd be grateful if you accepted my answer if this works for you. (hover to the left of answer and click the checkmark)